# Asynchronously create an array in angularfire

Tags: angularjs, angularfire

I am pretty new to angularfire but I am trying to create an array that is a list of names from a firebase array. When I look at what lists returns it seems to be what I want, so I know the function is working correctly.

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .factory('QuestionType', function ($firebaseArray, $firebaseObject, Ref) {
    var types = $firebaseArray(Ref.child('questionTypes'));

    var questionType = {
      list: function(){
        var lists =[];
        types.$loaded().then(function(){
          for(var i=0; i<types.length; i++){
            lists.push(types[i].name);
          }
          return lists;
        });

      }
    };  
    return questionType;
  });
```

In my controller I call that factory but because it is asynchronous, when I try and use the array in my view, it comes back as undefined.

```
$scope.questionType = QuestionType.list();
```

I figured out that I need to use $loaded.then in my factory, but how do I do a similar thing in my controller so that I can properly use it in my view?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return a new promise generated by `.then()`. Previously your list function didn't return anything.

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .factory('QuestionType', function ($firebaseArray, $firebaseObject, Ref) {
    var types = $firebaseArray(Ref.child('questionTypes'));

    var questionType = {
      list: function(){

        return types.$loaded().then(function(){
          var lists =[];
          for(var i=0; i<types.length; i++){
            lists.push(types[i].name);
          }
          return lists;
        });

      }
    };  
    return questionType;
    });
```

--

```
QuestionType.list().then(function(list){
  $scope.questionType = list;
});
```